Print statistics in train
To train cifar100 dataset, I find this function train, while I'm newer in Pytorch, I would like to understand the value 10000, because when I change it, the loss change
def train(net,trainloader,epochs,use_gpu = True):
    net.train()
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

    print(f"Training {epochs} epoch(s) w/ {len(trainloader)} batches each")

    # Train the network
    for epoch in range(epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            images, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 100 == 99:  # print every 100 mini-batches
                print("[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f" % (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 10000))
                running_loss = 0.0


What do you mean by "the loss change"? You are logging running_loss / 10000, if you change the denominator then the quantity changes. What is your question?

According to University of Central Florida, there are 10,000 images in the validation dataset of CIFAR-100. Maybe they meant to use the validation dataset instead of the training set for validation loss, and that might be where 10,000 comes from.

The code adds up the losses from 100 minibatches: running_loss += loss. Every 100 minibatches ((i + 1) % 100 == 0), you need to divide running_loss by 100 in order to get the average value. Then, the code resets running_loss (running_loss=0), before starting to add up the losses again for the next 100 minibatches.
There is a mistake in the code; it should divide by "100", not "10, 000", because you are accumulating 100 values each time.
